# REACT gives some errors that I am not sure why

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-redux

I am trying to learn REACT. I am following tutorials. I made everything according to the tutorials but I am not seeing exactly what I suppose to see instead I get the following error messages. 
this is the error I am getting:

```
SyntaxError: '.container.' is not a valid selector
<anonymous>                http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:7875:70
__webpack_require__        http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:20:12
<anonymous>                http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:48:19
__webpack_require__        http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:20:12
<anonymous>                http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:40:18
<anonymous>
```

here is my index.js code:
//go find the react library from node_modules and assign it to variable React.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

//Create a new component. This component should produce some HTML
//const = create some variable
const App = function(){
    return <div>Hey!</div>;
}

//web pack and babel translate for the browser.
//Take this component's generated HTML and put it on the page (in the DOM)
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

I don't understand what is going wrong, why it's saying  '.container.' while in my code it is '.container'

this is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/48938155eb24b4ccdde09426066869504c6dab3c/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  random stuff
    <div class="container"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

Also every time I change something in my code I have to stop the server and then run it again to see the changes, like here with the dot, I had to stop the server run it again to get rid of that error, but now I am using the ID instead of CLASS name and this solves the problem kind of. But every time with the server, is there something better to do?

Comment: `'.container.'` The error text has an extra dot `.` after `container` word but the render method does not have that extra dot. Check the render method again.

Comment: your `App` should extend `React.Component`.

Comment: @PrameshBajracharya no need to extending, OP has used a functional React component, also `.container.` is probably a typo, since his question doesn't contain it

Comment: @Prakashsharma i have already cahnged it but, when I go to my localhost its like I havent chagned it yet. I dont undertand I have removed the dot already!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to target an id instead of a class :

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/48938155eb24b4ccdde09426066869504c6dab3c/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  random stuff
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: When I changed something inside of my index.js and save when I go to my localhost I cant see the changes immediately, I have to stop server run it again then it will work, is this normal?

Comment: You need webpack-dev-server to do the hot-reload. You can simply create a new react app with `create-react-app` it'll handle this for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating `Functional Component` in react you need to pass `props` as parameter to the function.

```
const App = function(props){
   return <div>Hey!</div>;
}
```